# Android - RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am getting `RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` error and my ViewPager is not displaying the RecyclerView list. I create a new adapter object in the onCreate method of my fragment, which should be the right way to go. What am I doing wrong here?

Fragment file:

```
public class HomeCurrentFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recView;
    private EventAdapter eventAdapter;

    public HomeCurrentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(DummyData.getListData());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_current, container, false);

        // Get the recview for id
        recView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rec_list);

        // Set the layout to linear (as to grid)
        recView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
}
```

RecycleAdapter file:

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.EventHolder> {

    private ArrayList<EventItem> listData;

    public static class EventHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView title;
        private ImageView icon;
        private View container;

        public EventHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_text);
            this.icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.im_item_icon);
            this.container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_item_root);

        }
    }

    public EventAdapter(ArrayList<EventItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
    }

    @Override
    public EventHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.event_item, parent, false);
        return new EventHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EventHolder holder, int position) {
        EventItem item = listData.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.icon.setImageResource(item.getImageResId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: You just have one RecyclerView in your fragment? Your code is fine, I think that your problem is somewhere else. Can you post all your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public EventHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_item, parent, false);
        return new EventHolder(view);
    }
```

To:

```
public EventAdapter.EventHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_item, parent, false);
        return new EventHolder(view);
    }
```

I'm not sure why, hopefully someone can explain in the comments :)

Comment: This is the exact same code (the import statement changed, sure, but not relevant). You probably changed something else